# Change Caption URL in Lightbox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, caption, lightbox2

I've got the WP Slimbox2 plugin installed and I'm trying to have the caption's ULR point to a different site, not just the `img` URL.  Any ideas out there on how this can be done?

http://www.erisdesigns.net/wordpress/in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Simple question of replacing `<a>` and `</a>` with their HTML entity counterparts and using single quotes for the ref in the title attribute.  In case anyone is wondering ;)